# How get lot of params from url but without (&)?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, routes, route-model-binding

For now in Laravel i am testing url and in route i have

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'game'], function (){ 
 Route::get('/location/{location?}/action/{action?}/screen/{screen?}','GameController@index')->name('game.index');
});
```

In controller when i wanna pass params i have to type

```
example.com/game/location/1/action/update/screen/main
```

if i wanna pass only location and screen i have an error cause in url second param should be action.

I can create url like

```
example.com/game/?location=1&screen=main
```

and controller $request->screen and location works fine. But is any way to not using & ? and do this like:

```
example.com/game/location/1/screen/main
```

Answer (score 1):

For this route

```
Route::get('/locations/{location?}/actions/{action?}/screens/{screen?}','GameController@index')->name('locations.actions.screens.show');
```

In GameController index method, you can get these parameter as

```
public function index(Location $location, Action $action, Screen $screen) {
    // here you can use those models
}
```

if you are using route-model binding,

if not using

```
public function index($location, $action, $screen) {
    // here you can use these variables
}
```

If the route name is `locations.actions.screens.show` then in view, it will be

```
<a href="{{ route('locations.actions.screens.show', ['location' => $location, 'action' => $action, 'screen' => $screen ]) }}">Test</a>
```

Now, if you have some query parameter

then it will be like $http://example.com/?test="some test data"&another_test="another test"

you can access these parameter like

```
public function myfunction(Request $request) {
    dd($request->all());
}
```

Let's consider you want to retrieve all games, that belongs to a particular screen which belongs to a particular action and that belongs to a particular location, what your urls seems to be in your question, in that case, the url will  be

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'game'], function (){
 Route::get('locations/{location?}/actions/{action?}/screens/{screen?}','GameController@index')->name('game.index');
});
```

url seems to be `game/locations/1/actions/1/screens/1` where action and screen parameter can be optional

now in your controller index() method

```
public function index(Location $location, Action $action=null, Screen $screen=null) {
    //using the model instance you received, you can retrieve your games here
}
```

Comment: ok and how can i use that url example.com/game/locations/1/screens/2 i have an error

Comment: @Wraith first let me know, if you are using route model binding or you are just creating an url?

Comment: using route model to create url in view

Comment: In view, you can use route name, let me edit my answer in 1 minute.

Comment: In your example i still give action as param. i want in route go to method (index) and get params from request without bind params in route. Maybe is not possible :(

Comment: @Wraith If you want to access all screens, it the url will be like `/locations/{location}/actions/{action}/screens`

Comment: @Wraith In that case you the `index()` will be `index(Location $location, Action $action)`

Comment: @Wraith now, check it, I have added another example, to explain optional parameter.

Comment: nope :( still is error. i vahe to make Controller with Request only and pass params like example.com/game/?location=1&screen=main this works only for now. i dont lnow how to chnage that url to example.com/game/location/1/screen/main

Comment: @Wraith Have you seen the documentation of route-model binding?

Comment: @Wraith Also, can you explain the relationships of all these models?

Comment: There is no relation. Just simple url `example.com/game/?location=1&screen=main`  simple controller `index(Request $request) { dd($request->location, $request->screen, $request->action); }` and simple route: `Route::get('/', 'GameController@index')->name('game.index');` Models and relations doesnt matter.   just would like change url on `example.com/game/location/1/screen/main` and thats it

Comment: @Wraith Then what error you are getting for the code, I have written?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198879/discussion-between-prafulla-kumar-sahu-and-wraith).

Answer (score 1):

Your error makes sense

> URL second param should be action

because your route is with wild card location, action, screen

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'game'], function (){ 
 Route::get('/location/{location?}/action/{action?}/screen/{screen?}','GameController@index')->name('game.index');
});
```

To access this route you have to generate a URL with a wild card like

```
example.com/game/location/1/screen/main
```

and `example.com/game/?location=1&screen=main` not going to work because of your route URL and you can't access like `$request->screen`.

so your controller must be like

```
public function index($reuest, $location, $action, $screen){

}
```

You can directly access `$location, $action, $screen` and if you request something like

```
example.com/game/location/1/screen/main?param1=1&param2=2
```

Those are accessible through request like
`$request->param1` and `$request->param2`

Occasionally you may need to specify a route parameter, but make the presence of that route parameter optional. You may do so by placing a ? mark after the parameter name. Make sure to give the route's corresponding variable a default value:

```
Route::get('user/{name?}', function ($name = null) {
    return $name;
});
```

you can use Pattern Based Filters
You may also specify that a filter applies to an entire set of routes based on their URI.

```
Route::filter('admin', function()
{
    //
});

Route::when('admin/*', 'admin');
```

Comment: thats the point. how to set route to accept all request only without bind any params